# jQuery validation are not working

Tags: jquery

code:

```js
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#insert").click(function(event){
               event.preventDefault();
               name = $("#name").val();
               phone = $("#phone").val(); 
               email = $("#email").val();
               message = $("#message").val();
               if(name == '')
               {
                   $(".msg").text("Please enter your name");
               }
               else if (email !== "") {  
                    if (!isValidEmailAddress(email)) {
                        $("msg").show(); 
                        $("#email").focus(); 
                        return false;  
                    }
                } 
           });
        });
                function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-+\s]+")|([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*)|("[\w-+\s]+")([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*))(@((?:[\w-+]+\.)*\w[\w-+]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][\d]\.|1[\d]{2}\.|[\d]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        };
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post">
  <input class="form-control1" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" type="text">
  <input class="form-control1" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id"  type="text">
  <input class="form-control1" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone"  type="text">
  <textarea class="form-control1" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter Your Message" ></textarea>
  <input name="insert" id="insert" value="Submit" type="submit">
 </form>
```

In this code I have created a contact `form` and want to validate phone and email using jQuery. Now, when I use If statement and click on button it show me please enter your name after enter name when I click on button again it show me the same message. So, How can I fix this problem ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: "$("msg").show(); " can't work. Did you mean "$(".msg").show(); " ?

Comment: actually its ".msg" I have a div above the form where I have class msg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one instead of `alert` you can use `$('.msg')` but in your code, i'm found any `.msg` class element so there I used the alert instead.

```
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        function isValidEmailAddress(emailAddress) {
            var pattern = new RegExp(/^(("[\w-+\s]+")|([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*)|("[\w-+\s]+")([\w-+]+(?:\.[\w-+]+)*))(@((?:[\w-+]+\.)*\w[\w-+]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$)|(@\[?((25[0-5]\.|2[0-4][\d]\.|1[\d]{2}\.|[\d]{1,2}\.))((25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\.){2}(25[0-5]|2[0-4][\d]|1[\d]{2}|[\d]{1,2})\]?$)/i);
            return pattern.test(emailAddress);
        };
    </script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
           $("#insert").click(function(event){

               event.preventDefault();
               name = $("#name").val();
               phone = $("#phone").val(); 
               email = $("#email").val();
               message = $("#message").val();           
               if(name == '')
               {
                  alert("Please enter your name");
                   return false;
               }

                var filter = /^[0-9+]+$/;
                if (!filter.test(phone)){

                    alert("Invalid Phone");
                    return false;
               }
               if (!isValidEmailAddress(email)) {
                        alert("Invalid Email");
                        $("#email").focus(); 
                        return false;  
               }


           });
        });
    </script>

    <form method="post">

        <input class="form-control1" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Your Name" type="text">
        <input class="form-control1" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Id"  type="text">
        <input class="form-control1" id="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Enter Your Phone"  type="text">
        <textarea class="form-control1" name="message" id="message" placeholder="Enter Your Message" ></textarea>
        <input name="insert" id="insert" value="Submit" type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: addy may you show the code of phone no. validation on the same script.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!isValidEmailAddress(email)) {
       $("msg").show(); 
       $("#email").focus(); 
       return false;  
}
```

On This code of yours correct `$("msg").show();` With `$(".msg").show();`